# Qt Mac Build "Redefinition of `QObject`"

Tags: macos, qt, qmake

I a Qt project, which build perfectly on Windows, but on Mac I'm getting a really confusing error message saying there's a "Redefinition of `QObject`" in QSSLConfiguration class. I added this line in my `.pro` file:

```
macx {
    QMAKE_MAC_SDK = macosx
}
```

but it didn't help. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are mixing up shared libraries (e.g. debug/release or files with differing compiler settings) in your deployment. Do you manually deploy libraries? Use  macdeployqt. From the information you give, we probably cannot solve this here.